# ASP.NET MVC 3 : Validation get message list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I have this :

```
public class Customer
{
    [DisplayName("Lastname"), StringLength(50)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="My Error Message")]
    [NotEmpty()]
    public override string LastName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Firstname"), StringLength(50)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="My Error Message 2")]
    [NotEmpty()]
    public override string FirstName{ get; set; }
}
```

In the controller, I do this :

```
if (!TryValidateModel(myCustomer))
{
  //HERE
  ....
}
```

Where "HERE" is, I'd like get all error messages.

Some sample cases :

1. If "LastName" is missing I'd like get "**My Error Message**"
2. If both are mising, I'd like get a List (or other) with the values "**My Error Message**" and "**My Error Message 2**"

Any idea ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could get a list of all errors with their respective field and message like this:

```
var errors = ModelState
    .Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
    .Select(x => new { x.Key, x.Value.Errors })
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: No no I don't want all messages, I want just message for the field in error

Comment: @Kris-I, that's what you're gonna get => see the Where clause. It will take only the fields that have an error.